# Different templates for generating different PDF files related to a single node

Tags: 7, theming, files

Im using [PDF using mPDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_using_mpdf) to generate PDF files related to a node.
Inside the code of the module there is a preprocess function that add to `theme_hook_suggestions` a new pdf template that can be used when the view_mode is 'PDF' :

```
function pdf_using_mpdf_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view_mode'] == 'PDF') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $vars['type'] . '__pdf';
  }
}
```

this template works fine when I add inside my template directory a template file named like that : `node--node_type--pdf.tpl.php`.

The problem is that I need different PDF versions for the same node (one version with some fields, one with other fields, english version, french version)

how can I generate different templates for each PDF version knowing that this module use the view_mode 'PDF' to render the html content inside the PDF file :

```
$view = node_view($node, 'PDF');
$html = drupal_render($view);
// then generate the pdf using this rendered html
_pdf_using_mpdf_generator($html, $pdf_using_mpdf_pdf_filename);
```

So in this case I can't add new view modes for each version because the module will always generate the html according to the 'PDF' view mode.

These different files should be generated when the node is saved (`hook_node_presave`).

There is a function inside the api of this module to generate a pdf : 
`pdf_using_mpdf_api($html, $pdf_using_mpdf_pdf_filename = NULL)`. I will use it inside `hook_node_presave`

How can I assign to each PDF file a single template?

Comment: Is your site multilingual? I mean you need a version when your site is in English language and another version for french language.

Comment: no, the website has one language, only these pdf files should have two different languages